# Mutators - accessing attributes difference

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have in my model defined 2 mutators this way:

```
public function setUrlAttribute($value) {
    $this->url = $value;
    $this->domain = parse_url($value, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $this->fillSlug();
}

public function setTitleAttribute($value) {
    $this->title = $value;
    $this->fillSlug();
}

private function fillSlug() {
    $this->slug = $this->createSlug($this->title) . '-' . $this->domain;
}
```

However I noticed something strange - when having defined accessors this way when I set url and title in fact their new values are not saved. However (domain and slug) based on the same attributes are saved properly.

For example:

```
$model = Model::find(1); // url = 'http://oldurl.com', title = 'old title'
$model->url = 'http://testurl.com';
$model->title = 'test title';
$model->save();
$model = Model::find(1);
```

Now my attributes are:

```
url: oldurl.com
title: old title
domain: testurl.com
slug: test-title-testurl.com
```

This is quite strange because slug for example is base on `$this->title` so the value should be the same but it's not.

The solution to make it work is using:

```
public function setUrlAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['url'] = $value;
    $this->domain = parse_url($value, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $this->fillSlug();
}

public function setTitleAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['title'] = $value;
    $this->fillSlug();
}

private function fillSlug() {
    $this->slug = $this->createSlug($this->title) . '-' . $this->domain;
}
```

so not accessing attributes directly but using `$this->attributes['key_name']`

Now the question - why when using mutators value of field for mutator must be used using `$this->attributes` to work as intended whereas other field may use normal attribute accessing even for values that are changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tldr; Simply put - using `$this->title` in the mutator creates `public property` on the object, that is accessed later with `$model->title` (it never hits magic `__call` anymore), and it never touches attributes array, so in fact you're not changing the field.**

@AlleyShairu is right, however doesn't explain what happens, so here it goes:

```
// having this mutator
public function setTitleAttribute($value)
{
  $this->title = $value;
}

// and doing so:
$model->title; // 'old title'

$model->title = 'some string';

// then this is true:
$model->title; // 'some string'

// but
$model->getAttribute('title'); // 'old title'
```

That said, your attributes array is never touched with that mutator, so when you save the model, `title` remains unchanged.

That's why you should use `$this->attributes['attributeName']` in the mutator, rather than direct call `$this->attributeName`.

As a note: if it wasn't the case, you would end up with infinite recursive call to the mutator.

Comment: So in mutator I should  use `$this->attributes` - that's clear now. But what about other fields in mutator? Can I access other fields using `$this->property` or even use `$this->property` for mutated attribute when it's on right-hand side? I mean my second solution - is it completely safe now or maybe for `fillSlug` should I still use `$this->attributes['title']` instead of `$this->title` just in case?

Comment: You can use `->property` as long as it's not setting, but getting (of course accessors will be called if there are any). If in `fillSlug` you refer to `slug` attribute, then you can use it just like that, but have in mind that it will trigger mutator, if you define one for `slug` attr one day.

Answer (score 2):

From what I know if you have defined the mutator Laravel does not handle the `setAttribute($key,$value)` for that particular attribute. So you need to access it using

```
$this->attributes['key_name'] in your mutators.
```

When ever you are doing  $this->domain = parse_url($value, PHP_URL_HOST); Laravel is actually doing

```
$this->attributes[$key] = $value;
```

This is how setAttribute looks in laravel

```
public function setAttribute($key, $value)
{
    // First we will check for the presence of a mutator for the set operation
    // which simply lets the developers tweak the attribute as it is set on
    // the model, such as "json_encoding" an listing of data for storage.
    if ($this->hasSetMutator($key))
    {
        $method = 'set'.studly_case($key).'Attribute';

        return $this->{$method}($value);
    }

    // If an attribute is listed as a "date", we'll convert it from a DateTime
    // instance into a form proper for storage on the database tables using
    // the connection grammar's date format. We will auto set the values.
    elseif (in_array($key, $this->getDates()) && $value)
    {
        $value = $this->fromDateTime($value);
    }

    $this->attributes[$key] = $value;
}
```

As you can see in setAttribute method if a mutator function exists it just call that function and the line `$this->attributes[$key] = $value;` never executes.

Comment: Ok, but why in first case slug is created properly (it uses `$this->title`) and this property is set using `$this->title = $value;` without using `$this->attributes`. Is in this case attributes and normal properties become 2 different sets ?

Comment: I see your point and `$this->title` is also getting its value from the attributes array. It is indeed a strange behaviour or are we missing something? Looking forward to the solution.

Comment: This method from eloquent, that is called by __set, allow you access to the attributes via dynamic properties. All attributes in that array are automatically accessible via the dynamic properties. It is handled by the last line of that method.  $model->attribute = ''; calls __set which calls setAttribute. and $model->attribute; calls __get which calls getAttribute. This is all based around the magic methods __get and __set.